# I'm trying to learn sqlite queries but keep getting this error

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery, relational-database, sql-except

I'm trying to write an SQLite Query using sqliteonline.com that can:

Find the names of faculty members who teach in every room in which some class is
taught.

Here are the relations:
[image]

This is what I have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT F.fname
FROM Faculty F
WHERE NOT EXISTS (( SELECT *
                    FROM Class C )
                    EXCEPT
                   (SELECT C1.room
                    FROM Class C1
                    WHERE C1.fid = F.fid ))
```

AND This is the error I get:

[image]

I've double checked and the parenthesis are balanced. So I'm kind of confused on where to go from here.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must remove the parentheses that enclose each of the subqueries and select the same columns in each of them (I guess only `room` is needed):

```
SELECT F.fname
FROM Faculty F
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT room FROM Class C 
                   EXCEPT
                   SELECT C1.room
                   FROM Class C1
                   WHERE C1.fid = F.fid 
                 )
```

Also `DISTINCT` is not really needed, because you are selecting unique (I believe) `fname`s from `Faculty`.

Answer (score 2):

This reads like a relational divison problem. I would address this with a canonical approach, using joins and aggregation:

```
select fname
from faculty f
inner join class c on c.fid = f.fid
group by fname
having count(distinct c.room) = (select count(distinct room) from class)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `select *`.  Just select the same column on both sides of the `except`:

```
SELECT F.fname
FROM Faculty F
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT c.Room
                  FROM Class C
                  EXCEPT
                  SELECT C1.room
                  FROM Class C1
                  WHERE C1.fid = F.fid
                 )
```

Note:  You should probably select more than just the first name.  The rows in `Faculty` should be unique.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply. So I just entered your answer but im still getting the same error.

Comment: @PeterShepherd . . . SQLite doesn't like the extra parentheses.